# Custom Control in Windows Phone: Creating Numeric PasswordBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I have a custom TextBlock with my custom validation, but I also need to use a Password Box functionality to. How can I make a custom Numeric PasswordBox?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a PasswordBox to your XAML like so:

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="MyPasswordBox" KeyDown="MyPasswordBox_KeyDown" />
```

And then use the KeyDown event to remove all key presses that are not from 0 to 9, like so:

```
private void MyPasswordBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = (e.Key < Key.D0 || e.Key > Key.D9);
}
```